# where can i find toolbox icon for visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

i need icon(image) of all controls in toolbox in visual studio.is there any link that i can use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Icons are stored as an embedded resource in the corresponding .NET assembly hosting the control. So there's no link that you can use. You will need to extract it from the assembly. For example to extract the icon for a button from the System.Windows.Forms assembly you could use this:

```
    var assembly = Assembly.Load("System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
    using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("System.Windows.Forms.Button.bmp"))
    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
    {
        byte[] image = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
        File.WriteAllBytes("button.bmp", image);
    }
```